# Should I use Ant.Design or MaterialUI or React-Bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use one of the theme library with reactJs.
My requirements are:

- Theme Control
- Fast Development
- Easy to Read Code and Debug
- If necessary, I can easily modify my Components UX in future
- and obviously, Mobile Friendly

Answer (score 29):

Its good to use a UI framework for react as they give you pre-build components that are efficient, responsive, and customizable. However, each framework has its pros and cons. Before choosing a framework I recommend checking how good the documentation is as well as checking the stars on GitHub although it's not the only metric to judge how good a framework is. Every framework is great in its own place however here are some features of `Ant Design`, `Material UI`, and `React Bootstrap`.

> **Ant Design**

- High-quality React components out of the box.
- Written in TypeScript/ Supports Typescript.
- Powerful theme customization in every detail.
- Internationalization support
- Great documentation
- Open-source.

> **Material UI**

- Premium themes available.
- Not easy to customize.
- Based on material design spec developed by Google.
- Lots of components.
- Open-source.

> **React-Bootstrap**

- More control over form and function of each component.
- Easy Responsiveness.
- Great documentation.
- Open-source.
- One of the oldest React library.
- Mobile first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will go with Ant or Bootstrap. MaterialUi is very complex.

Comment: I found a lot of documentation of Ant (certainly Ant pro) is still in Chinese. Won't that hinder development?

Comment: I don't think so, plus you can always use google translate.

Comment: Bundle sizing and customization will be much better in case of material-ui

Comment: Material UI works really well but it has a steep learning curve.

Comment: Material-UI also provides TypeScript

Comment: Material-UI is not developed by Google. It is based on Google's Material Design, but they are separate things.